# Android: Looking to create a background with multiple parts and background colors

Tags: android, android-layout

I am looking to create a button with text and a background and near the end of the background i want the text to have a different colored background, however i want it to still be part of the same button.

Here is an example of what i am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeLayout or any other layout instead of a button and just handle click events like a button.

Or you can use Layer List, something like this (untested), and you will need to handle text to fit in somehow.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:left="35dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="35dp"/>
        <solid android:color="color1"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="35dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="35dp"/>
        <solid android:color="color2"/>
    </shape>
</item></layer-list>
```